# how to change style of selected text from a list in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

thanks in advance.
I have a list of text view in react native, which are populated from json. I need to change the style of a text view when user selects one. Here how do i manage the state of style.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You can manage this using state, by check if clicked unique is same as in state . like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this using state, by check if clicked unique is same as in state . like that. –

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing with a [flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), the first example is a list of selected or not components. If you post some sample code, we can try to adjust it to your code.